# Building GNU part of GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, gnu

I have successfully built the `Linux Kernel 3.13.6` and ran it in `QEMU`. Since it is just the kernel, it will eventually complain that it cannot find `init` or `sh`, etc.

Therefore, it is necessary to build the GNU utilities for Linux (which makes it GNU/Linux). However, how would someone do that? How do you build the utilities for Linux?

Is it as simple as downloading & compiling w/ GCC and then copying onto a formatted disk?

Comment: http://linuxfromscratch.org/

Comment: What do you do ? LFS? LFS is very hard, why LFS? you can remaster from a powerful distro such as debian.

Comment: Sorry, but if you build the GNU part of "GNU/Linux" you are still *very, very* far from having a working system (GNU software proper is just a small fraction of a working Linux system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the very basic UNIX commands are part of [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) if that's what you mean, like `ls`, `mv`, etc.

> How do you build the utilities for Linux?

Like you build anything else under Linux.  Download the source, read the instructions the developer has provided, and follow them - typically involving making sure you have the prerequisites such as libraries, etc. available, changing to the source directory, maybe running a `configure` script, and then issuing a `make` command or two.

In coreutils case, you want to read and follow [this](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/plain/README-hacking).